# Batch output file without expanding variables

Tags: windows, batch-file

Let's say I have something that is:

```
echo %cd%
echo %~f0
```

and I want to output that to foo.bat:

```
echo echo %cd% > foo.bat
echo echo %~f0 >> foo.bat
```

this wouldn't work, though, since the variables would be expanded. I could do:

```
echo echo %%cd%% > foo.bat
```

to fix the first one, but I don't know how to fix it for the second one.

Comment: `echo echo ^%^~f0 >> foo.bat` ?

Comment: Outputs too foo.bat as: `echo ^~f0 `

Comment: Oh ok, `echo echo %%^~f0 >> foo.bat`

Comment: Brilliant, thanks. Will you submit it as an answer or should I?

Comment: OK, I have submitted it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escape the percent with another percent, and escape the tilde with the [batch file escape character `^`](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php), e.g.

```
echo echo %%^~f0 >> foo.bat
```

Comment: Ah, thanks for the explanation along with answers; I had a few others I needed to output that were different.

Comment: It is not necessary to escape the tilde, `echo echo %%~f0 >> foo.bat` is enough...

Comment: That's what I get for getting an answer via `^%~f0` then seeing the escape didn't work and adding `^%^~f0` and thinking that was right, then correcting only the missing percent with `%%^~f0` and never trying the first correct escape without the second escape `%%~f0`.

Answer (score 3):

In case you want to echo `%MY_VAR%` without expansion, escaping as `%%MY_VAR%%` does not work. Only escaping as `%MY_VAR^%` or `^%MY_VAR^%` will output `%MY_VAR%` as intended.

Also be advised that when quotes are present you have to escape them as well to avoid expansion. See the following examples:

```
set FOO=BAR
echo %FOO%
BAR
echo %%FOO%%
%BAR%
echo %FOO^%
%FOO%
echo ^%FOO^%
%FOO%
echo "%FOO%"
"BAR"
echo "%%FOO%%"
"%BAR%"
echo "%FOO^%"
"%FOO^%"
echo "^%FOO^%"
"^%FOO^%"
echo ^"%FOO%"
"BAR"
echo ^"%FOO%^"
"BAR"
echo "%FOO%^"
"BAR^"
echo ^"%FOO^%"
"%FOO%"
echo ^"^%FOO^%"
"%FOO%"
echo ^"^%FOO^%^"
"%FOO%"
```